# In Xcode 13 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor: not working properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have updated my Xcode into 13, later on words in my old project navigation and tab bars colours was changed to transparent.

My Code is

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor AppThemeColour]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

I tried to add background colour but title and images of the navigationBar not appering.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor bOneAppThemeColor];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor AppThemeColour]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

I have studied this below link but i'm unable to implement it in Objective C

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682420

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost everything you're doing is wrong (and has been wrong for several years). You need to use UINavigationBarAppearance (and UITabBarAppearance) and apply them to both the bar's `standardAppearance` and its `scrollEdgeAppearance`. Set the appearance's background color, not its tint color. And do not touch the `translucent` property ever.

In this simple example, we make all navigation bars adopt your theme color. Modify to suit your needs and desires:

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    UINavigationBarAppearance* appear = [UINavigationBarAppearance new];
    appear.backgroundColor = [UIColor AppThemeColor];
    id proxy = [UINavigationBar appearance];
    [proxy setStandardAppearance: appear];
    [proxy setScrollEdgeAppearance: appear];
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```